# Creating new variable based on few conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

In the attached image, I want to create two groups in R: If half of the days of any ID is >=90, return A in New category, if else, return B in New Category. I also want to retain/return all other variables.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0iNU.png)

I apologize, I am pretty new to R.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following with `dplyr` package. After grouping by `ID`, create the `new_category` by adding up instances where `days` is greater or equal to 90, and then seeing if greater than "half" of the rows for that `ID`. If it is, set `new_category` to "A" (otherwise "B").

```
set.seed(123)

library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  visit_date = Sys.Date() + sample(1:100, 9),
  days = c(90, 30, 30, 120, 90, 20, 90, 90, 30),
  ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3)
)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(new_category = ifelse(
    sum(days >= 90) >= n()/2,
    "A",
    "B"
  ))
```

This is a similar approach with base R:

```
df$new_category = ave(df$days, 
                      df$ID, 
                      FUN = function(x) ifelse(
                        sum(x >= 90) >= length(x) / 2, 
                        "A", 
                        "B")
                      )
```

**Output**

```
  visit_date days ID new_category
1 2021-10-26   90  1            B
2 2021-12-13   30  1            B
3 2021-11-15   30  1            B
4 2021-10-09  120  2            A
5 2021-12-01   90  2            A
6 2021-11-06   20  3            A
7 2021-11-14   90  3            A
8 2021-11-07   90  3            A
9 2021-12-31   30  3            A
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(visit_date = structure(c(18926, 18974, 18946, 
18909, 18962, 18937, 18945, 18938, 18992), class = "Date"), days = c(90, 
30, 30, 120, 90, 20, 90, 90, 30), ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
3, 3), new_category = c("B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A")), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```